# Ansible how to set_fact with condition or var base on condition

Tags: ansible

I have 3 types of servers: dev, qa and prod. I need to send files to server specific home directories, i.e:

Dev Home Directory: /dev/home

QA Home Directory:/qa/home

PROD Home Directory: /prod/home

I have var set as boolean to determine the server type and think of using set_fact with condition to assign home directories for the servers. My playbook looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  var:
    dev: "{{ True if <hostname matches dev> | else False }}"
    qa: "{{ True if <hostname matches qa> | else False }}"
    prod: "{{ True if <hostname matches prod> | else False }}"

  tasks:
  - set_facts:
      home_dir: "{{'/dev/home/' if dev | '/qa/home' if qa | default('prod')}}"
```

However, then I ran the playbook, I was getting error about 'template expected token 'name', got string> Anyone know what I did wrong? Thanks!

Comment: you appear to be treating `else` as if it were a filter, and not a keyword in jinja2; you will also likely benefit from using groups in your inventory (which also allows for hostname pattern matching) combined with `group_vars` to avoid having to perform two tasks in your playbook that are easily established as facts before the playbook even runs

Answer (score 1):

Use [match](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings) test. For example, the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    dev_pattern: '^dev_.+$'
    qa_pattern: '^qa_.+$'
    prod_pattern: '^prod_.+$'
    dev: "{{ hostname is match(dev_pattern) }}"
    qa: "{{ hostname is match(qa_pattern) }}"
    prod: "{{ hostname is match(prod_pattern) }}"
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        home_dir: /prod/home
    - set_fact:
        home_dir: /dev/home
      when: dev|bool
    - set_fact:
        home_dir: /qa/home
      when: qa|bool
    - debug:
        var: home_dir
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e hostname=dev_007

  home_dir: /dev/home
```

Notes:

- The variable *prod* is not used because */prod/home* is default.
- *prod/home* is assigned to *home_dir* first because it's the default. Next tasks can conditionally overwrite *home_dirs*.
- Without the variable *hostname* defined the playbook will crash.

---

A simpler solution that gives the same result is creating a dictionary of 'pattern: home_dir'. For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    home_dirs:
      dev_: /dev/home
      qa_: /qa/home
      prod_: /prod/home
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        home_dir: "{{ home_dirs|
                      dict2items|
                      selectattr('key', 'in' , hostname)|
                      map(attribute='value')|
                      list|
                      first|default('/prod/home') }}"
    - debug:
        var: home_dir
```

Comment: Thank you! The first one worked. I haven't tried the second one yet.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an alternative method to achieve this. This kind of extends the `group_vars` suggestion given by **@mdaniel** in his comment.

Ansible has a ready-made mechanism to build the variables based on the inventory hosts and groups. If you [organize your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#id14), you can avoid a lot of complication in trying to match host patterns.

Below is a simplified example, please go through the link above for more options.

Consider an inventory file `/home/user/ansible/hosts`:

```
[dev]
srv01.dev.example
srv02.dev.example

[qa]
srv01.qa.example
srv02.qa.example

[prod]
srv01.prod.example
srv02.prod.example
```

**Using `group_vars`:**

Then you can have below `group_var` files in `/home/user/ansible/group_vars/` (matching inventory group names):

```
dev.yml
qa.yml
prod.yml
```

In `dev.yml`:

```yml
home_dir: "/dev/home"
```

In `qa.yml`:

```yml
home_dir: "/qa/home"
```

In `prod.yml`:

```yml
home_dir: "/prod/home"
```

**Using `host_vars`:**

Or you can have variables specific to hosts in `host_vars` directory `/home/user/ansible/host_vars/`:

```
srv01.dev.example.yml
srv01.prod.example.yml
# and so on
```

In `srv01.dev.example.yml`:

```yml
home_dir: "/dev/home"
```

In `srv01.prod.example.yml`:

```yml
home_dir: "/prod/home"
```

These variables will be picked based on which hosts you run the playbook, for example the below playbook:

```yml
---
- hosts: dev

  tasks:
  - debug:
      var: home_dir
    # will be "/dev/home"

- hosts: prod

  tasks:
  - debug:
      var: home_dir
    # will be "/prod/home"

- hosts: srv01.dev.example

  tasks:
  - debug:
      var: home_dir
    # will be "/dev/home"

- hosts: srv01.prod.example

  tasks:
  - debug:
      var: home_dir
    # will be "/prod/home"
```

Comment: Thank you! I have host group set in my inventory. However, when I run playbook, I only run it against single host as user enters from Jenkins. So I need  to put something in playbook to determine which group the host belongs to.

Comment: If you go through the link in my answer, you can see that you can set host specific variables as well for group. Use `host_vars` directories to define them. I will update the answer.